# Error getting when creating instance of MetadataService Class

Tags: c#

Cannot convert type 'MetaDataAPI.MetadataRefrence.QuickActionLayoutItem[]' to 'MetaDataAPI.MetadataRefrence.QuickActionLayoutItem'

MetadataService service=new  MetadataService ();
I am getting error

Comment: is this a typo? -- 'Refrence` is spelled 'Reference'

Comment: Can you please post code snippet ?

Comment: You should past more of your code. Actually this single line might be not enough to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a very old post but adding here so that if somebody else is having the same issue.
I had the same issue while using Microsoft's XSD to generate a class for the XML returned by Metadata API.
I manually Find [][] and Replace [] from proxy class generated by VS and it worked without any issue.